# Jon sabe que existimos (lo cual es mucho decir porque él creó el mundo)

Tags: discusión, estado-completado

Nuestro ya casi ídolo (y diamantado) [g3rv4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4), tuvo uno de sus meetings en SO en el cual, el invitado de honor era Jon Skeet.

En su primer encuentro, se sacó una selfie.. a 15 metros.. claro, así cualquiera tiene selfies. Sin embargo, lo [tuiteó](https://twitter.com/g3rv4/status/963882587407179776), y lo nombró...

Y comenzó la magia...

Jon le contestó casi inmediatamente, que no sea tímido y salude...

Y si él va a saludar, qué mejor que mandarle un saludo todos, ya que seamos fan del lenguaje que seamos, ¡es JON por dios!

Así que en un ataque de cholulísmo egoísta, si él tenía su foto, yo quería mi autógrafo.. y construí esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual fue recibido muy bien por Jon (digamos que parece de un niño de 6, pero bueno, es PAINT y un MOUSE).

Y acá ocurrió la magia.

G3rv4 consiguió su foto [magica](https://twitter.com/g3rv4/status/964503359523840000)

Y nosotros.. un e-autógrafo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único que nos faltaría, es que Jon nos conteste este Post, con un saludo y creando un usuario en SO esp, ¡solamente para que podamos decirle a los de po y ru que a nosotros sí nos saludo!

[image: introducir la descripción del enlace aquí]

Creo que después de recibirnos, esto es recibirnos por segunda vez.

y si alguien llegó hasta acá y no sabe quien es Jon...

[image: perfil para Jon Skeeten Stack Overflow, Preguntas y respuestas para programadores y profesionales de la informática]

Comment: Creo que esta publicación merece la etiqueta [meta-tag:estado-completado] :D

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBEn3a4TIUw

Comment: Como para no saber quien es Jon... Grande!!

Comment: @gbianchi hay sitios que sí permiten embeber vídeos ([ejemplo](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/568/4078)).

Comment: @gbianchi a los de ja. no les vamos a decir?

Comment: @Jorgesys no sabria decirte quien seria su dios.. es mas.. debe ser el demonio...

Comment: OMG!!!! OMG!!!! OMG!!!! Esooooo!!!! Nuestro cosmos ha sido elevado a niveles nunca antes vistos, contamos con la bendición del gran, ilustre y legendario JON SKEET, avatar maestro nivel Ninja del C#!!! :')

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA Ni había visto ESTO!!!!

Comment: Mi mas sincero agradecimiento al que ha puesto el gif ;)

Comment: Espera @gbianchi , que es "cholulismo", únicamente encontré [esto](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/cholulo).

Comment: @Jorgesys exacto!!!! seria lo mismo con una persona famosa... sea del ambito que sea..

Comment: Alguien que me contenga que estoy a segundo de ponerle este post en un tuit a Jon...

Comment: @gbianchi nadie te contuvo... dónde está el tuit??? daaale que fuiste uno de los que saltó en twitter a decirme que pida la foto cheeeee

Comment: Como me reí leyendo esto xD! Paint skills over 9000

Comment: @gbianchi donde quedó el famoso tuit?

Comment: https://twitter.com/gonzabianchi/status/966794040216838144

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Y aquí les dejo el saludo de Jon:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es un grande!! Y no habla nada mal español!!